# Constness in brackets operator in custom container

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I have a custom class with two overloaded brackets operators -- setter and getter. As you know they look somewhat like this

```cpp
class IntContainer {
public:
    int const & operator[] (size_t i) const;
    int & operator[] (size_t i);
}
```

The problem I'm facing now, is that I have to check when the value was set or when it was just accessed, that is I need to track all the changes in my container. It's hard since always only non `const` operator is called, for example

```cpp
container[i] = 3;  // Non const operator[] called
x = container[i];  // Again, non const operator[] called
```

In two cases above I need to differ inner behavior in container. So is there any way to explicitly call different operators in cases like above. I don't want to use `const` instance of container and to define another functions like `set` and `get`, though I'm looking for smoe right design pattern.

Thanks!

Comment: I mean, you could make sure that the object `container` is const within some context, or use a const reference to it, like `const IntContainer& const_container = container; x = const_container[i];`. This would force the const operator to be used. Also, you can of course use named setters and getters. Depending on why you need this, there is always the option of not returning the actual variable (reference to int in your case) but a viewer to that variable which makes sure to call something when an assignment is made. Best might be if you give us your actual context.

Comment: @Aziuth Container is another class’ member, in some methods of containing class it can be modified in others it can’t. Moreover, if I capture it in lambda, then it can’t be captured as const reference, isn’t it.

Comment: I don't think what you want is robustly possible at all. A user of your container could do `int* r = &container[i]; /* whatever */ *r = 3;` and there is no way container can detect the last assignment.

Comment: You cannot universally keep track of when modifications happen to your container. At least not while keeping with plain `int&` as return type. How do you want to guard against `int* hah = &yourContainer[0]; /* a long time later */ *hah = 10;`? Edit: Damn, ninja'd.

Comment: So what would be the best solution from the design perspective?

Comment: Alternative: Introduce a Setter function. Comment out the non-const operator. Build. See what breaks. Replace them with Setter function. Make the Setter function track your changes. Done!

Comment: The easy route is telling people how to use your container correctly and say "it's undefined behavior if you make a mistake". The hard way involves some ugliness that would make your container incompatible with existing standard library algorithms and/or lead to awkward syntax (essentially explicit get/set functions, possibly behind a proxy object). But there is a lot of design space in between, and you have almost no constraints in your question, so we can't really tell what would be a good design, not to mention "the best".

Answer (score 7):

One trick is to create a proxy object.  This lets you overload the assignment operator and put your tracking logic into there and then you can guarantee that any writes are captured. If you have

```
class Proxy
{
    int& val;
    Proxy(int& val) : val(val) {}
    Proxy& operator=(int new_val)
    {
        // do tracking stuff
        val = new_val;
    }
    operator int() { return val; }
};
```

then you can adjust `IntContainer` to

```
class IntContainer {
public:
    int operator[] (size_t i) const;
    Proxy operator[] (size_t i);
};
```

and now you'll call the tracking code when the user actually tries to assign into the reference.

Comment: @Denisof A decent optimizer should optimize most/all of it away.  Depending on what you are doing there might be a slight performance penalty but you'd need to profile/benchmark to really know.